# Put pdf files which I download from Firebase Cloud Storage to recyclerview using Kotlin

Tags: firebase, kotlin, android-recyclerview

> I have prepared recyclerview to show pdf files but when I try some functions to put pdfs into recyclerview they didin't show. Is any function to do this?

This is my adapter and here probably all is well

```
class AdapterKarty(private val fileList: ArrayList<plik>): RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterKarty.ViewHolder>(){



    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): AdapterKarty.ViewHolder {
        val a = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.karta_pliku,parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(a);


    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: AdapterKarty.ViewHolder, position: Int) {


           var item = fileList[position]

            holder.dokument.text = item.Name

    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return fileList.size
    }


    inner class ViewHolder(itemView: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){

        var dokument: TextView = itemView.tv_dokment
    }
}
```

In list I use class plik where i declare only name because here i try put name of pdf

```
class plik( var Name: String?=null){

}
```

And here I have my main class where I try put those files to recyclerview

```
class Dokumenty : AppCompatActivity() {


    private  var stor: FirebaseStorage?=null

    private var storageReference = stor?.reference

    lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView
    private lateinit var listaPlikow : ArrayList<plik>
    private lateinit var myAdapter: AdapterKarty

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dokumenty)

        stor = FirebaseStorage.getInstance()





        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView)


        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)

        listaPlikow = arrayListOf()

        myAdapter = AdapterKarty(listaPlikow)

        getFiles()

    }





    private fun getFiles() {

        var pliki = storageReference?.child("Pliki/")



    }







}
```

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: I dont know what is wrong because when i try some ways mostly nothing is showing and in other ways app closing without any errors.

Comment: If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question.